# perl regular expression s/(\s*&\s*)$//)

Tags: regex, perl

I am not getting the what is regular expression  `$cmd =~ s/(\s*&\s*)$//` meaning.

Answer (score 4):

It is detecting the last part in $cmd that has "    &    " and removing that.

For example, if $cmd contains `$cmd = 'command params1 param2  &  '`

then it will remove the last part and result is `command params1 param2`.

#### Explanation

```
Perl regex structure: s/REGEX_TO_SEARCH/REGEX_TO_REPLACE/
Here REGEX_TO_REPLACE: empty
     REGEX_TO_SEARCH: (\s*&\s*)$
     Four parts:
       \s* : Any number of space
       &: occurence of &
       \s*: any number of space again
       $: end of string
```

#### Pictorial Demonstration

*note that the highlighted part is also captured that can be accessed by $1*
[image]